# How to use a command line argument of apple script in do script?

Tags: applescript

In terminal.app I am executing the command.

```
 osascript filename.scpt 'argument1' 'argument2'
```

The **filename.scpt**  script will set it's variable named **scriptName** from the second argument it receives when run from the CL.

```
  set scriptName to item 2 of argv
```

The **filename.scpt** will then use the variable **scriptName** in a **do scrip**t command for the do script's argument "**UIASCRIPT**"

```
        do script "instruments -w <have given my device id>  -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate com.merucabs.merucabs -e UIASCRIPT  -e " & scriptName & " UIARESULTSPATH ~/Desktop/traceoutput;" in newWin
```

But when I run the code I get an error saying:

> 2015-06-05 12:28:07.258 instruments[3667:109611] Argument 'UIASCRIPT' does not point to a valid script. Using script defined in template.

Comment: The AppleScript command is "do shell script".

Comment: @Zero "scriptname" refers to the variable to store "the script I need to perform UI automation" I need to just add it in the command I mentioned above in the middle

Comment: @Zero thanks for taking your time in going through and hope you could answer my question ...

Comment: So what are you entering as argument2. Could the script path be wrong or the script have syntax errors

Comment: You have got `-e` twice in your command - seems unlikely.

Comment: I figured it out sorry the issue is with placing -e before the script name rather than the after it ,thank you ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out thank you all !!

the issue is with placing -e before the script name rather than the after it ...

```
    do script "instruments -w " & device_id & " -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate " & bundle_name & " -e UIASCRIPT " & script_path & " -e UIARESULTSPATH " & trace_output & ";" in newWin
```